# The name 'devicetypes' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get data out of my db but i am getting the above mentioned error on this line. Please HELP!!!!

```
join specvalue in db.Types on devicespecifications.DeviceTypeFKID equals devicetypes.DeviceTypeID
```

I have Tried switching the equals but it doesn't work. Please Help

```
List<DeviceDetails> devicedetails = (
                                from devices in db.Device
                                join devicespecifications in db.DeviceSpecifications on devices.DeviceID equals devicespecifications.DeviceFKID 
                                join devicetypes in db.Types on devices.DeviceTypeFKID equals devicetypes.DeviceTypeID
                                join specvalue in db.Types on devicespecifications.DeviceTypeFKID equals devicetypes.DeviceTypeID // This Line is giving me the above mentioned error
                                join devicehistories in db.DeviceHistory on devices.DeviceID equals devicehistories.DeviceFKID
                                join locations in db.Locations on devices.LocationFKID equals locations.LocationID
                                join ips in db.IP on devices.DeviceID equals ips.DeviceFKID

                                where devices.DeviceID == id
                                select new DeviceDetails()
                                { 
                                  DeviceID = devices.DeviceID,
                                  DeviceName = devices.DeviceName,
                                  EntryDate = devices.EntryDate,
                                  AssignDate =  devices.AssignDate,
                                  DeviceStatus = devices.DeviceStatus.ToString(),
                                  MACAddress = devices.MACAddress,
                                  DateRepaired= devicehistories.DateRepaired,
                                  Remarks=  devicehistories.Remarks,
                                  SpecificationType = devicespecifications.DeviceTypeFKID,
                                  devicetypes.DeviceTypeID,
                                  SpecificationValue =  devicespecifications.SpecificationValue,
                                  FamilyIP =  ips.FamilyIP,
                                  ChildIP = ips.ChildIP,
                                  LocationTypeValue =  locations.LocationTypeValue,
                                  DeviceTypeValue =  devicetypes.DeviceTypeValue
                                }).ToList<DeviceDetails>();
        return devicedetails;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mentioned row:

```
join specvalue in db.Types on devicespecifications.DeviceTypeFKID equals devicetypes.DeviceTypeID
```

you use `devicetypes` name again but you should use `specvalue` in this line.